# Use differentiation to find the a power series for 1/(x+1)^2

Tags: calculus, power-series

I did see this discussed in another question; however, I did exactly what the answer suggested and still do not seem to get the solution.

The question is to use differentiation to find the representative power series of $1/(x+1)^2$

I could easily see that the derivative of $-1/(x+1)$ is $1/(x+1)^2$.

So, my goal was to find the power series for $-1/(x+1)$ and then take the derivative of that.

I found the power series for $-1/(x+1)$ to be: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^\left(n+1\right) x^n$.
Then I simply took the derivative of that power series to get:
$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n) (-1)^\left(n+1\right) x^\left(n-1\right)$

Can't see where I went wrong.

Book answer:  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n (n+1)x^n$
Makes no sense to me.  Maybe I didn't find the original power series correctly?

Comment: Shift the index! And note the term at $n=0$ vanishes

Comment: but both my answer and theirs start the series at $n=0$.  I had thought of that

Comment: It's a dessert topping! It's a floor wax! It's $\,1-2x+3x^2-4x^3+\dots!$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same. In your answer, the $n=0$ term is just $0$ because of the multiplication by $n$:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n+1} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n+1}x^n.
\end{align}
Now, change the index of summation, by letting $n=m+1$. Then,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(-1)^{n+1}x^n=\sum_{m+1=1}^{\infty}(m+1)(-1)^{m+1+1}x^{m+1}=
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^m(m+1)x^{m+1}
\end{align}
Now, you can relabel the indices however you like:
\begin{align}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(-1)^m(m+1)x^{m+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n+1)x^{n+1}=
\sum_{@=0}^{\infty}(-1)^@(@+1)x^{@+1}=
\sum_{\star=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{\star}(\star+1)x^{\star+1}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!!!